# Why my program is going on Infinite loop when i am trying to read multiple line input from TCP Server

Tags: java, tcp, socket.io, infinite-loop, tcpclient

This is my TCP client java code:

```java
socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8088);
out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String result = "";
while (inputStream != null) {
    result += inputReader.readLine();
}
out.writeUTF(result);
System.out.println(result);

socket.close();
out.close();
```

The `while` loop is getting executed infinitely.

I need a solution for this problem.

Comment: `inputStream` is never modified inside the loop, how and when should it become `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check when `readLine()` *returns* `null`, not when `inputStream` *becomes* `null` (which it never will):

```java
string s = inputReader.readLine();
while (s != null) {
    result += s;
    s = inputReader.readLine();
}
```

Or:

```java
string s;
while ((s = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
    result += s;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to nullify your inputStream within the while loop with some condition, for it to break.

Answer (score -1):

`inputStream` is always having a value i.e. its not `null`, so you keep looping and appending.

Does that make any sense? You can check like `inputReader.readLine() != null` instead:

```java
string line;
while ((line=inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
    result += line;
}
```

Comment: You need to call `readLine()` once per loop iteration, not 2 times.